# ConstraintLayout Guideline with scroll

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview, design-guidelines

I'm building a screen with ConstraintLayout , My screen need to have scroll since it's a long list a data. For normal screen i use Guideline and arranging the views based on percentage. How can i do a scrollable screen with Guideline ?